# How do I git clone a pull request instead of the original version?

Tags: github

How do I clone a pull request here: https://github.com/sushant10/HQ_Bot/pull/57

When I do git clone https://github.com/sushant10/HQ_Bot it only clones the default version. How do I clone the version with the pull request?

EDIT: The pull request is not merged and I do not own the repository.

Comment: Welcome to SO. It is for specific programming problems, not help with other programming sites.

Comment: I see questions like these on this site.

Comment: Where? Please provide a link so that we can close it. **This is not a GitHub help site.**

Answer (score 0):

You actually can't "clone" a pull request. I think what you want to do is to clone the branch that is to be merged. Which in your case is: https://github.com/tanujyadav97/HQ_Bot/network

Comment: remote: Not Found
fatal: repository 'https://github.com/tanujyadav97/HQ_Bot/network/' not found

Comment: That wasn't the direct link to the repo, just to the github page. Your Link is just 2 clicks away. https://github.com/tanujyadav97/HQ_Bot.git

Answer (score 0):

First, clone origin repository:

```
git clone https://github.com/sushant10/HQ_Bot.git my-fork
```

Then fetch PR branch into local branch:

```
cd my-fork
git fetch git@github.com:sushant10/HQ_Bot.git pull/57/head:my-local-branch
```

Where `57` is a ID of PR and `my-local-branch` is name of your local branch, where you can find fetched commits from PR.

Source: [Checking out pull requests locally](https://help.github.com/articles/checking-out-pull-requests-locally/)

---

You can also clone repository of PR author: https://github.com/tanujyadav97/HQ_Bot